# Good book recommendations on matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm a high school student and now we are learning matrixes.
I want to find a good matrix book but I don't know which one should I pick.
-Does anybody have any suggestion?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest Linear Algebra and Its Applications by Gilbert Strang for beginner. It's pretty intuitive and instructive and you can also find open course by the author from MIT OCW.

Answer (score 0):

When you say you want to learn "matrixes" you really mean you want to learn linear algebra. [Here](http://bayesianthink.blogspot.com/2013/09/the-best-books-for-linear-algebra.html#.UsbvCBVx05k) is a list of books that are good to learn linear algebra.